# How to align the DIVs to ceate a box that looks like a search box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout that involves an outer `DIV` with two inner `DIV`s.

Both of the two inner `DIV`s need to be vertically centered.

One of the inner `DIV`s needs to be anchored to the right edge of the outer `DIV` (with a few px margin).

The other inner `DIV` needs to be hrizontally centered in the whole outer `DIV`.

Something like this.

```
___________________________
|                         |
|[     some text      ][S]|
|_________________________|
```

The 'some text' `DIV` can sit behind the 'S' `DIV`, or beside it, that doesn;t really matter.

I can't use `::after` as the 'S' `DIV` needs to have an `onClick` event attached to it (it's actually a search button within the `DIV`)

I have tried lots of difefrent ways to acheive this, but nothing is quite right.

Right now I have the following which uses `display: flex` which is close but not quite right.

```css
#resultBox {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#resultText {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-size: 2.8vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.18em;
}

#searchButton {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="resultBox">
  <div id="resultText">
    <span id="part1">Here's</span>
    <span id="part2">some</span>
    <span id="part3">text</span>
  </div>
  <div id="searchButton" onClick="search();">&#x1F50E</div>
</div>
```

That gets me close, but I want the `searchButton` `DIV` to stick to the right regardless of the content of the `resultText` `DIV`.
I guess I could use a `table`, but that seems a bit old fashioned.

Comment: Are you searching for: `contenteditable="true"` ?

Comment: Nope, sorry. The question is nothing to do with being able to edit the content... It's about the alignment of the search icon DIV. I will edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Ok it was just a wonder, please have a look to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your text center and set your search icon to the right you can just set margin: auto to your text:

```
#resultText {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-size: 2.8vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.18em;
  padding-left: calc(1.5vw + 40px); /** To compensate icon size on the right we add padding-left similar width **/
  margin: auto;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
#resultBox {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#resultText {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-size: 2.8vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.18em;
  padding-left: calc(1.5vw + 40px); /** To compensate icon size on the right we add padding-left similar width **/
  margin: auto;
}

#searchButton {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="resultBox">
  <div id="resultText">
    <span id="part1">Here's</span>
    <span id="part2">some</span>
    <span id="part3">text</span>
  </div>
  <div id="searchButton" onClick="search();">&#x1F50E</div>
</div>
```